# SQL Server + PHP - stored procedure with multiple SELECT returns garbage output

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, output, multiple-select

I'm trying to create an SQL Server stored procedure with output

**SQL Server**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test1
   @in_var  VARCHAR(20),
   @out_var VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Company WHERE COM_ID=1
    SELECT @out_var = 'Hello, ' + @in_var
END
```

**PHP**

```
$result = "";
$sql = "{CALL sp_test1(?,?)}";
$param = array(
    array("Andy",SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($result, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR), SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50))
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $param);
echo $result;
```

When I echoed the result, it returns garbage text instead of *'Hello, Andy'*. I realize that I cannot put more than 2 select statements, if I removed the first select then the output is ok. But I need the select statement for some logic.

```
    SELECT * FROM Company WHERE COM_ID=1 -- will be used in logic later
    SELECT @out_var = 'Hello, ' + @in_var -- i just want to output this!
```

So how can I force to output only the LAST SELECT statement??

Comment: try adding ';' between you select queries: 'SELECT * FROM Company WHERE COM_ID=1;SELECT out_var = 'Hello, ' + in_var' or maybe you want to get both variables in one query?

Comment: Added the ';' doesn't seem to help :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use another variable just for control? Depending on the value, you return one select or the other. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test1
    @option  INT,
    @in_var  VARCHAR(20),
    @out_var VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   IF @option = 0
       SELECT * FROM Company WHERE COM_ID=1
   ELSE
       SELECT @out_var = 'Hello, ' + @in_var
END
```

So in this case, you pass like `@option = 1` and the procedure returns `"Hello"`. When you need the other for your logic, you call the procedure and pass `@option = 0`

Comment: Let's just say I need both the SELECT together, no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to get both of them on one query?:
well if you want you can do this:

```
SELECT *, @out_var = 'Hello, ' + @in_var FROM Company WHERE COM_ID=1
```